# Why is this DropDownList data binding to a List<String> not working?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to bind a `List<String>` to a `DropDownList` in a user control. I *think* I'm doing the right thing, but it seems that after my code executes the **bindings are cleared**. Here's the code for review!

**User control:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="subjectNameDropDown" runat="server"/>
<asp:DropDownList ID="yearLevelDropDown" runat="server"/>
```

**Auto-generated designed code-behind:**

```
public partial class NewSiteMetadataUserControl {
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList subjectNameDropDown;
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList yearLevelDropDown;
}
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class NewSiteMetadataUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        subjectNameDropDown = new DropDownList();
        yearLevelDropDown = new DropDownList();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        EnsureChildControls();

        // Attempt 1
        List<String> subjectNames = GetSubjectValues();
        foreach (var subjectName in subjectNames)
            subjectNameDropDown.Items.Add(subjectName);
        subjectNameDropDown.DataBind();

        // Attempt 2
        List<String> yearLevels = GetYearLevelValues();
        yearLevelDropDown.DataSource = yearLevels;
        yearLevelDropDown.DataBind();
    }
}
```

*Should this approach work?*

If it should, *how can I debug what happens after the code executes?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was `CreateChildControls`. Somewhere in my attempts to make this work I added this method that initialises the controls. This isn't necessary and in fact caused the data bindings to be wiped out, as it was automatically called by the framework after `OnLoad`.

The solution was to remove this method and the call to `EnsureChildControls`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this approach should work, here's why it currently isn't,

- A DropDownList done with `DataBind` needs a `DataSource`. This is why Attempt #1 is not working.
- If you're binding to a `List<string>`, there is no clear key/value pair to bind to. This is why when binding to a `List<Person>` (for example), you need to override `.ToString()` in the `Person` class to provide the key/value binding, or manually set the `DataTextField`, `DataValueField`.
- There is no way for ASP.NET to work out a key/value pair for a `string`.

Think about **what HTML** you want. What should be the key/value for a simple string? Doesn't make sense does it.

Since you don't really care about the "key" (only what is displayed), i suggest you bind to a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` instead.

Either make your method return that, or iterate through the list and add them to the dictionary with an index.